# Searching through a HashSet using .contains()

Tags: java

I have a hashSet of strings, used to represent a RushHour state. The hashSet contains all of the previously visited states.

I call a function to return the next moves available from a given state and check if they have been already been visited using the code:

`if(!(visitedHash.contains(childBoards.get(i).Convert())))`

Then if the state has not been visited I add it to the queue, to solve using Breadth First Search.

The problem is when I write this line of code:

`if(visitedHash.contains(currentBoard.Convert())){
                System.out.println("Whats Going on!!??");
            }`

when I poll off a new board, I get many states printing "What's Going on!!??"

This should not be possible! Should it? I've just checked if they were included and they were added to the queue so the must have passed the IF statement!

here is my full code of the search method:

```
public void search(Board b){    
    //--------Perform Breadth First Search on Board b--------//Method to solve the puzzle using Breadth First Search
    System.out.println("Attempting to solve the Board using Breadth First Search...");
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();                                                     //capture the start time for the method
    queue.add(b);                                                                           //push the input board onto the front of the queue
    while(!solved){                                                                         //while the board is not solved
        currentBoard = queue.poll();                                                        //assign the top of the queue to currentBoard
        currentBoard.print();                                                               //print the board to the screen (PRINT EVERY BOARD VISITED)
        System.out.println(currentBoard.Convert());
        System.out.println("This board is on level " + getLevel(currentBoard));
        //System.out.println("Visited Boards size: " + visitedHash.size());
        if(visitedHash.contains(currentBoard.Convert())){
            System.out.println("Whats Going on!!??");
        }
        boardsExplored++;                                                                   //increment the number of boardsExplored
        if(currentBoard.isGoal()){                                                          //if the board is the goal state
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();                                               //capture the end time for the method
            long duration = endTime - startTime;                                            //calculate the duration for the method
            time = (double)duration / 1000000000.0;                                         //convert the time to seconds
            System.out.println("SOLVED! Goal car is Free!");
            System.out.println("Time taken to solve = " + time + " seconds");               //print the time taken in seconds
            System.out.println("Moves made = " + (boardsExplored - 1));                     //print the number of boards explored to reach goal
            visitedHash.add(currentBoard.Convert());                                        //add the board (when converted to a string) to the list of visited boards              
            printSolution(currentBoard);                                                    //Call method to print shortest path found
            write(b);                                                                       //Call method to write data to the file
            solved = true;                                                                  //set solved to true
            return;                                                                         //exit the loop
        }
        visitedHash.add(currentBoard.Convert());                                            //add the board (when converted to a string) to the list of visited boards              
        childBoards = currentBoard.getChildMoves();                                         //call getChildMoves on the currentBoard to retrieve all available boards
        for (int i = 0 ; i < childBoards.size() ; i ++){                                    //for every one of the child boards
            if(!(visitedHash.contains(childBoards.get(i).Convert()))){                      //if the child board has NOT previously been visited
                queue.add(childBoards.get(i));                                              //add the child board to the queue and loop back    
                parent.put(childBoards.get(i), currentBoard);                               //Map the child board to its parent
                level.put(childBoards.get(i), getLevel(currentBoard));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does Convert do?

Comment: Make sure that the return type of `Convert()` implements `hashCode()` and a correspondig `equals(..)` method. Then checl if contains finds the element directly after you put it in the `HashSet` for testing if the Set works correctly with your elements.

Comment: Have you implemented `equals` for the return type of `Convert()`? If not please post your `Board` class as well.

Comment: Have you thought of adding an `else` block to the `if(visitedHash.contains(currentBoard.Convert()))` condition? Your console might not be printing "Whats Going on!!??" on the first iteration of your `while(!solved)` loop

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in comments, you probably need to create an appropriate hashCode and equals method for whatever the return type of Convert() is.

Comment: Convert simply converts a RushHour board to a string. "-" for blank spaces and then letters for vehicles

Comment: Why do I need to I need to mess with HashCode and equals methods? I am only comparing one string with a list of strings using .contains

Comment: @Anthony If you are using `HashSet` you need to implement those methods for the `contains()` method to work properly

Comment: if the return type of Convert() is String, then String already has equals and hashCode implemented, and it should be working.

Comment: I know Kevin, that is what I thought. Somehow duplicate boards are getting through that IF statement and I cannot see how#